# What is the difference between if(map[arr[i]]) and if (map.find(arr[i]) != map.end()) ? When looking for a value in the map

Tags: c++, maps

The task is to find common substring. The solution worked when I changed my if statement. So what is the difference between ->>>>> if(map.find(...) != map.end()) and  if(map[a..[..]])

Correct code:

```
 unordered_map<char, int> map;   

for(int i = 0; i < s1.size(); i++)        
    map[s1[i]]++;   
             *emphasized text*
  for(int i = 0; i < s2.size(); i++)        
    if(map[s2[i]])            
      return "YES"; 
       
  return "NO";
}
```

Comment: `*emphasized text*` is not valid C++. Post real code.

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
 if(map.find(X) != map.end())
```

Checks to see if `X` exists in the map and will return true if it is there (thus entering your test condition).

The line:

```
if(map[<X>])
```

If `X` exists in the map then it will return the associated value. If `X` does not exist in the map then it will be inserted and a default value will be constructed and will be the result of the `operator[]`. It is the value returned by `operator[]` that is then converted to a bool to decide if the branch is taken.

The difference between the two:

- `if(map.find(X) != map.end())`
  Does not change map.
  Branch if the item `<X>` exists in the map.
- `if(map[<X>])`
  Mutates the map if the key 'X' does not exist.
  Branch depends on the value associated with the key `X`.
  Note: A default constructed value does not always evaluate to false it will depend on the type. Though in your case `unordered_map<char, int> map;` the value type is `int` and the default (or default value constructed object in the map) for an integer is 0 and thus converts to false.

Answer (score 0):

One difference is that `if(map[s2[i]])` will insert a `0` in the `map` for that key. A side effect is that the subsequent `if(map.find(...) != map.end())`  will find that `0` value.